# Generic tool to create software configuration GUIs

Tags: linux, open-source, gui, information-management

Looking for a tool that can take a description of configuration options (e.g. IP address, retry interval, maximum retries, etc.) including range of acceptable values and create a GUI that collects that information from a user.

- Needed for Linux, but cross platform would be better.
- Runs locally would be acceptable, network accessible is better
- Inter-field dependencies would be a nice-to-have (Doesn't matter what "Retry Interval" is set to if "Retry" isn't checked)

Ideally with hooks so that the file format the information is written out in can be configured.  If it supports it's own structured format I can handle a back end translation to the format I want.

The use case is creating individual configuration tools for a large collection of applications currently managed and configured by a single web GUI as a cooperating system.  The existing GUI was manually created over the years and is too big and complicated to use for individual pieces of the system that we would like to spin off as standalone tools.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly what you are asking for, but it can serve the same end goal. Take a look at Config, http://www.configapp.com/, a config file manager. It's SaaS but can be installed on-premises on Windows, Linux, or Docker. Doesn't have inter-field dependencies support at the time of this writing. Supports XML, JSON, INI, properties, YAML, TOML. You can use Config as a web GUI to manage multiple systems, applications, modules, environments and instances.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

I love version control and git.

But during the last years I came to this conclusion: configuration is data. And data needs to be stored in a database.

For me this means PostgreSQL.

There is a web framework called django which enables you to get an admin interface with nearly no programming.